# Automatically arc land when Phabricator differential review accepted

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

How can I configure Phabricator to perform an arc land when a differential commit is approved?  I've seen this workflow at my previous job, but configuring Phabricator has been tougher than I'd imagined.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible with Phabricator. There's exist another tools `arcyd` that can do that. https://github.com/bloomberg/phabricator-tools